# How to link to controller actions in a Craft 3 plugin?

Tags: craft3

I cannot find any documentation that specifies how to link to controller actions which return a rendered template in CP.

Let's say I have a plugin called `waffles` and my namespace is `Very\Waffles`. I have a controller named `SyrupController` and it's residing in `Controllers` directory (note the capitalized directory name). So the namespace for it would be `Very\Waffles\Controllers`.
An action `actionPour()` - how can I register a route that would call this action if I land on the `/admin/waffles` URL?
I've walked through the steps with a debugger and It's trying to check if a `SyrupController` exists but how can it, if only `Very\Waffles\Controllers\SyrupController` exists? Thus it fails to register that route and fails.

Any help much appreciated!
Here's some code:

```
    Event::on(
        UrlManager::class,
        UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES,
        function (RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {
            $event->rules['waffles'] = 'waffles/syrup/pour';
        }
    );
```

It shouldn't be possible to link to a controller by using this string, so I'm guessing an array that specifies the `SyrupController::class`, but there's no documentation about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently I figured it out. Would still like a better way of doing this, but here's the solution I found to be working:

In your `Plugin` class, you have to add a `public $controllerMap` array. For my example plugin above, here's what I would have to add to that `$controllerMap` array:

```
use Very\Waffle\Controllers\SyrupController;

class Plugin extends \craft\base\Plugin
{

    /** @var array */
    public $controllerMap = [
        'syrup' => SyrupController::class,
    ];

    // other code here, obviously
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your code should work as you suggested without the additional stuff.

```
Event::on(
    UrlManager::class,
    UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES,
    function (RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {
        $event->rules['waffles'] = 'waffles/syrup/pour';
    }
);
```

**Clarification:**

plugin-name = Waffles

controllerName = SyrupController

functionName = actionPour()

With the information above you should be able to call the function in the controller with waffles/syrup/pour, and as you stated, the `rules['waffles']` would be your URL.

Comment: At the time of the question Craft plugins had no automatic controller map included. Now they have it but earlier you had to do what Gustav described

Comment: I had wondered if that was the case. Thanks for clarifying.